# Swift - How to access a UIView's Constrained coordinates

Tags: ios, swift

I have a playing card image that in a test program I want to move around. To do this I keep changing its center coordinates in a timer loop. So far so good. However I have positioned the card on the Main.storyboard using constraints but when I interrogate the cardImage.center I get the actual coordinates of where I place the card on the board not the location it snaps to based on the constraints. How to I get these final coordinates?

Comment: At what point in time are you getting the coordinates? at viewDidLoad?

Comment: Make sure you are retrieving the coordinates after the view has been fully loaded by the controller. viewDidLayoutSubviews is a good place to check for subview info and start to manipulate them, though viewDidLoad will usually work for most cases as well.

Comment: add some code please to show what you're doing

Comment: I have accessed the .center coordinate in both viewDidLoad and later in the button press action that starts the animation. Both time it reports the original coordinates not the constrained coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually prefer to check constrained coordinates in viewWillAppear rather than viewDidLayoutSubviews because this last one is called more than once.

You can also call self.view.layoutIfNeeded() at some places to make sure the layout is updated at this time.